# Apigee Proxy Seems to "Redirect" to my Underlying API

Tags: apigee

When I create an API proxy in Apigee (my account is new), and then paste that newly created url into my browser, I get an unexpected result.

The data returns as I would expect from my underlying API on my system.  But, the URL in the Browser changes from the Apigee URL to my original URL.

I don't really even want the user to know that my underlying URL exists.  We are planning on putting Client Side SSL in place so that only the Apigee system can talk to our underlying API, but this is still behavior that I wasn't expecting.

Any help or guidance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that you would see your targets url in your browser is if your target is returning a 302 redirect with said url in the response.  This often happens if in apigee your pointing to a http target with a rewrite rule that auto redirects to an https address.

The best way to fix this would be to change your target to an https address so the redirect does not happen.

If it is some other reason you should look at the trace tool to see exactly what traffic is going through apigee, this can give you a good perspective on what changes on the request as it goes through the platform.